# How can I get the current_user from Devise in Rails for JS use

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the current_users username and id from devise in rails without having to store it in the DOM for later access.  Are there any techniques/strategies to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

While Rails is just the backend on your server and javascript is the frontend on client-side you defenitely need to put something inside html or ajax it.

a few approaches:

**1.**
just write it into the body with an data attribute

```
<body data-username="<%= current_user.username %>
```

**2.**
making an ajax call to the server to receive that information (pseudocode)

```
$.ready() {
  $.getJSON(/api/user-information, function(data) {
    username = data.username
    settings = data.settings
    unread_messages = data.unread_messages_count
  }
}
# /api/user-information
def user_info
  render json: {username: current_user.name, settings: {enabled: false, wants_chat: true}, unread_messages: 10}
end
```

or **3.** maybe this gem is helping you
https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma

if you need that information to make some ajax-calls on certain urls or whatever - i always would go with solution #1. thats why data-attributes exist in HTML5